# Two points of contact while rolling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Suppose a sphere is rolling on horizontal surface. The point of contact is the instantaneous center of rotation. It's velocity momentarily is zero. So in a time $dt$ it'll stay where it is.
However during this time $dt$ the point next to this contact point at its right side will move forward and down, thus after time $dt$ we will have two points in contact with the horizontal surface. Which is wrong.

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Dt is a point in time with interval zero (infinitesimal).  There is no motion in zero time.  It can have a speed, represented by dx/dt where x represents position, but dx is zero distance.  So each point can have a velocity over dt, but cannot move unless a nonzero interval is assumed.

Answer (score 9):

> It's velocity momentarily is zero. So in a time $\mathrm dt$ it'll stay where it is.

This is the same kind of argument as saying that a ball thrown upwards will have a time of momentary stop, and then continuing to say that it will thus not fall down. Very Zeno, and this is where it is wrong.

Comment: There is no zeno here. I said velocity is zero not acceleration is zero

Comment: @Kashmiri if acceleration is not zero then it will not "stay where it is", the velocity will change. It is exactly the same as the example given in this answer

Comment: @AnderBiguri , if v =0 then in time dt, dr =v.dt=0. After dt yes the velocity changes and the object moves .

Comment: @Kashmiri No, `F=m*a`, if there is a force, there is an acceleration, and the integral of this acceleration will describe the velocity. Also, a dt describes change. As when you trow an object towards the air, the object, in its maximum position is at v=0. But because a is not 0, the ball will change velocity and be of opposite sign. Is a=0? no, absolutely no, even if v(t=t_up)=0. because v(t) is a function of t, even if at some particular time t v(t1)==0, it does not make all dv(t)/dt equal to zero.

Comment: @Kashmiri "if v =0 then in time dt, dr =v.dt=0" - no, this is not true. The point of derivatives is, roughly, that time $dt$ is sufficiently small so that we can consider the function to be linear. If there is nonzero acceleration, that means that in the $dt$ timeframe, the velocity graph is tilted with the slope $a$ (i.e., it's *not* constantly zero); at the beginning of the interval, the velocity $v_0$ is zero, but it changes uniformly via $v = at$ (in the linear approximation), so that at the very end of $dt$ you get $v_1 = adt$

Answer (score 6):

[image]

the rolling condition is

$$dx-R\,d\varphi=0$$

and because $~x(t)~$ and $~\varphi(t)~$ accrue simultaneously (at the same time) ,you get just one contact point not two.
hence

$$\frac{dx}{dt}-R\,\frac{d\varphi}{dt}=0$$

Comment: Hi and thanks. I had asked what was wrong in my approach. It'll helpful if you address that

Comment: @Kashmiri    Your approach is  ? , that you obtain the contact point by applying first translation and then rotation, but this not correct, both are applying at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

The point on the wheel that was in contact with the ground at time $t_0$ will *not* be in contact with the ground at any later time $t > t_0$, no matter how short the time interval $\Delta t = t - t_0$ may be.

(Of course, the same point will be *again* in contact with the ground whenever $\Delta t$ is a multiple of the wheel's period of revolution, but that's not what we're interested in here.)

Yes, the instantaneous velocity of the point (with respect to the ground) at time $t_0$ is zero, but only because that's the exact moment when the point's velocity changes from (asymptotically) straight downwards to (asymptotically) straight upwards.  In particular, the acceleration of the point (i.e. the time derivative of its velocity) is *not* zero, but rather points upwards towards the center of the wheel.

In fact, the acceleration vector of *every* point on the wheel *always* points towards the center of the wheel, and its magnitude is constant for each point and equal for all points at the same distance from the center.  You can easily see that if you look at the system in a frame of reference tracking the wheel's center, where the wheel simply undergoes a pure rotation and each point simply traces a circular path around the center at constant angular velocity, and thus a constant-in-magnitude centripetal acceleration.  And adding a pure translation at constant velocity *does not change the accelerations*, since the added constant linear velocity cancels out when you take its time derivative.

---

(In other words, the analogy with an upwards thrown ball at the apex of its arc in [naturallyInconsistent's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768862) is in fact perfectly appropriate.  But it's not *obviously* appropriate until you've managed to convince yourself that the trajectories of the ball and the point on the wheel's rim in fact do look the same locally, at which point you no longer really need the analogy.)

Answer (score 0):

The location of the contact point can move independently from the material of the wheel at the contact point.

The contact point itself is defined as the point where the wheel touches the ground; it is not a fixed point on the wheel. The location of this point travels at the same velocity as the center of the wheel. The material of the wheel itself is still at rest there, i.e. if you mark the contact point on the wheel this marking has a velocity of zero.